# Fisher Information Calculation Extended

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, statistics, tensor

Given your data matrix `X.shape = (n, d)`, and a single predictor variable's estimated values `y_pred.shape = (n,)`, one can compute the Fisher Information `I` like so:

```
    V = diags(y_pred * (1 - y_pred)) # V.shape = (n, n), sparse from scipy.sparse.diags
    I = X.T.dot(V).dot(X) # I.shape = (d, d)
```

Now let's say I'm wanting to extend this to `k` data matrices, so `X.shape = (k, n, d)`, giving me `k` FIM `I.shape = (k, d, d)`. Would it be more efficient to loop over the `k` matrices, or is there a linear algebraic way that would speed this up?

Thanks!

Comment: You can look at `np.tensordot`.

Comment: What are the typical values of `k`, `n`, `d`?

Comment: I'm building a forward selection procedure, so `d` typically starts at 2 and ends up around 20-30? `k` would then decrease with each step.

Answer (score 2):

**Approach #1**

We could do it in two steps for a vectorized solution with `np.tensordot` and `np.einsum` -

```
parte1 = np.tensordot(X, V, axes=(1,0))
out = np.einsum('ijk,ikl->ijl',parte1, X)
```

For a sparse matrix `V`, use the following to get `parte1` :

```
(X.swapaxes(1,2).reshape(-1,n)*V).reshape(k,d,n)
```

**Approach #2**

Alternatively, in one `einsum` call -

```
np.einsum('ijk,jl,ilm->ikm',X, V, X)
```

Note: We could experiment with `optimize=True` in `einsum` call to bring about further speedups with the newer NumPy versions.

Comment: The tensordot threw an error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 1309, in tensordot
    if as_[axes_a[k]] != bs[axes_b[k]]:
IndexError: tuple index out of range`
but they have those axes?
`>>> V.shape
(100, 100)
>>> X.shape
(10, 100, 7)`
Or do I need to add a `np.newaxis` to `V`?

Comment: @BradFlynn What are the shapes of `X` and `V`?

Comment: `X.shape (10, 100, 7)` and `V.shape (100, 100)`

Comment: @BradFlynn Works fine for me. Check again?

Comment: It may be because `V` is a sparse matrix, which is necessary since `n` will get big in most or all of my use-cases

Comment: @BradFlynn Maybe you should have mentioned that bit up-front :)

Comment: @BradFlynn Convert it to a regular array with `.toarray()` and see?

Comment: same issue due to memory constraints, but on a smaller scale, it works

Comment: @BradFlynn What are k,n,d for the actual large scale case?

Comment: `n` usually sits around a million, `k` starts out around ~120, and `d` usually ends up anywhere around 10-40.

Comment: I just ran some time trials for comparison: with `n = 500000`, `d = 10`, and `k = 60`, this method took on average 15.96 seconds, while looping through the 60 took only 3.74 seconds on average. You mentioned something about `optimize=True` for `einsum`? You think this would make a difference?

Comment: @BradFlynn Nah, keep the loop.